# PageList Cannot convert method group 'pagedlistpager' to non-delegate type in ASP.NET Core MVC 2.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1, pagedlist

Trying to add paging to users in my ASP.NET Core MVC 2.1 web app. Everything seems to be working except `@Html.PagedListPager` - I get an error:

> Cannot convert method group 'pagedlistpager' to non-delegate type 'object'.

Also I noticed under Dependencies > NuGet > PagedList.Mvc > PagelistList(1.17.0) a yellow exclamation mark. I wonder if pagelist is supported in core 2.1? I tried to downgrade it and update it and it still has the mark. Is there a solution or work around?

```
@Html.PagedListPager (Model, page => Url.Action("Index",
     new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
```

Comment: That looks like an old MVC package that not supported anymore (see [here](https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList)). You probably need to upgrade to the one that supports .NET Core (see [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/X.PagedList.Mvc.Core))

Comment: Thanks I testing it out now, I got the code for learn.microsoft.com it was just updates 2 weeks ago.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That error is happening because there is a space before the opening `(` meaning Razor treats it as `@Html.PagedListPager`.

Also as pointed out, that package hasn't been updated since 2013 so is not supported in .NET Core. The official site for that package suggests you use [X.PagedList.Mvc.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/) instead.

Comment: Yea that fixed the error but Like you both recommended its outdated, Im testing it out now

Comment: Thanks it worked with the same code all I had to do was download the packages X.PagedList.Mvc.Core and use all the same code. Just change my @using in my view to X.PagedList.Mvc.Core

Answer (score 2):

X.PagedList.MVC.Core worked perfectly I used the same exactly code and documentation on [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) to get it to work. When I used

```
@model X.PagedList.PagedList<MyProject.Models.ApplicationUser>
@using MyProject.Utility
@using X.PagedList.Mvc.Core
@using X.PagedList;
```

In my view the error went away